# Scientific terms (reinforcer, chemicals)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

i'm trying to translate an english article in french. This article explains some scientific experiments. I have the following sentence:

> At the top of our human reward list are food, sex, love, friendship,
>   and novelty. These are called ‘natural reinforcers,’ as contrasted
>   with addictive chemicals.

I understand the second sentence as "These are a natural help, unlike addictive chemical products".

Am i right? I'm not sure how to translate "**reinforcers**". And, in this case, does "chemicals" refer to articial addictive products (drugs, ...) or does it refer even to chemical substances in the brain, like dopamine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *reinforcers*, another word with roughly the same meaning, and much easier to translate in French, is [*stimulant*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stimulant).

> an agent (as a drug) that produces a temporary increase of the functional activity or efficiency of an organism or any of its parts

From these sentences, *chemicals* is most likely to refer to alcohol, nicotine and drugs, and not body chemicals like dopamine (which are also produced as a result of the 'natural reinforcers').

Comment: Je ne sais pas.